# Is this an object or a function?

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial on machine learning, and learning python at the same time. There is a part of code which I don't understand:

```
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
>>> clf = GaussianNB()
>>> clf.fit(X, Y)
```

I don't understand the second line. Is it a new instantiated object and the brackets are there because it's a constructor? If it is, how can I differentiate it from a function being assigned to a variable? I know that in this example it's rather clear because of this line `clf.fit(X, Y)`, but I want to know what to do in other cases.

Comment: You can think of a class as a function for creating new objects. As long as it returns what you want, why do you need to know if it is a class for a function?

Comment: A little research would make this clear: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

Comment: I understand that it's a class, but is there any way to differentiate it without checking the documentation?

Comment: You could check `type(whatever)` if you really want to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object. `GaussianNB` is callable. Adding the `()` calls it. The return value of that call is entirely up to the object.

In this specific case, `GaussianNB()` instantiates a new `GaussianNB` object and returns it.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but from what I understand all python libraries contain objects, that have required functions, but never only functions?

Comment: @faken functions are objects, so this question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @faken In python functions are actually objects that you can call and not instantiate

Comment: @Matei So what makes them objects then? It sounds like a description of a function to me.

Comment: @faken Think of a function as an object that stores a routine, with special syntax to invoke that routine.

Comment: @gyre Ok I think I will have to get used to that.

Comment: @faken when you call `a_function(args....)` you get a result, it can be an int it can be anything
but when you call `a_class(args ..)` you get a new instance of that class, meaning a new memory zone and a new structure

Comment: `functions` is a subset of `objects` which are callable. `classes` are another subset of `objects` which, from the docs: [Class instantiation uses function notation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 2):

In this example you can use

```
>>> type(clf)
<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB'>
```

and see that his is a class. You can also use

```
>>> help(GaussianNB)
```

to get more info.
Python guidelines recommended

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

and for functions

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

You can read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Answer (score 0):

It is an object.  The third line is a method you can always do 'type(object)' to see what type it is so try type(clf)